# Mysqli_connect() does not work on live server without showing any error message

Tags: php, mysqli

`Mysqli_connect()` works well when I am on my local server.
But, now that I'm on the live server, it does not work.
However, `Mysqli_error()` does not show any error message.
I tried to use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set("display_errors", "on")` to force `mysqli_error()` to return an error message but it does not.
But I must mention that: when I enter consciously a bad parameter to `mysqli_connect()` (like a bad password), then `mysqli_error()` return an error.

Please help me

Comment: How do you know it "does not work"? How do you know it's Mysqli_connect() and not something else?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php should be used for connection error. Are systems using same PHP version, and both (this one) have mysqli enabled?

Comment: Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically.

Comment: @user3783243 better to switch on overall automatic mysqli error reporting than to rely on the old-fashioned individual error reporting